# How to test performance of SharePoint app as it has user authentication functionality and it generate "client-request-id, how to dynamically pass it

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-2016, jmeter-5.0

I'm performing load testing on SharePoint and I have to test authorization as it generates client request id every time how to automate or bypass it.

Or another way to perform the testing on the SharePoint

I have recorded the script using JMeter and validating it and now it is showing error's